# Error 403 when migrating website to a different server caused by gad cookie

Tags: apache, cookies, server, centos

I just migrated my website to a different hosting. Some visitors are reporting that they get a 403 when they try visiting the website, but for others it looks normal. Doing some debugging, we found that the error goes away when visitor clear the gad cookie (I think that one is from google analytics).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Maybe force the visitors to clear the cookies if they visit the website and they already have it?

I've tried clearing the cookies from PHP but it doesn't work, since the visitor never gets to the page.

The website is https://www.abcwords.net/?end=rby